# Scroll View not working? Works in design preview but not emultor/device

Tags: android, scrollview, design-view

I cant see the issue here at all . Registration screen but I cant scroll down to the register button. In the logcat it says I/StackScroller:ADJUST STACK.TRANSLATION. Could this be something to do with it. In my design view I can see it scrolling but when i run it it does not!
I have tried most things Ive seen online, restarting the device, android studio etc dont know why it is working with the design view and not on the emulator

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#03a9f4"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_Image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_here"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_no"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone Number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/dob"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Date of birth">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <!--  Datepicker used to select DOB ,hide the large calender and display the spinner calender style -->
        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="148dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:spinnersShown="true"


            />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emergency_contact"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Emergency Contact">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emergency_contact_phone"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Emergency Contact Phone Number">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="registerUser"
            android:text="Register" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_to_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back to login screen" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this for Edit Text

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutemail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textNameAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: so change this <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText to EditText?

Comment: Got it working deleted the xml and created a new one and it worked! I do hate android studio sometimes